How to make a Sci Chart Contour Plot
I am trying to make a contour diagram using scichart js. Previously i was using matplot in python which just required the x , y and z values[arrays] and creates the plot. However this seems a bit differrent in scichart js.
The Sci Chart documentation has provided an example but i am still confused on what format it expects the data and how the x,y,z points can be used to make the contour.
Here all x ,y and z are multidimensional arrays. They have the same shape.
// Create the uniform heatmap data series. Pass heatValues as number[][]
const heatmapDataSeries =  new UniformHeatmapDataSeries(wasmContext, {
// 2d zValues array. Dimensions [height][width]
  zValues,
// xStart, xStep, yStart, yStep defines the x,y position
 xStart: 0,
 xStep: 1,
 yStart: 0,
 yStep: 1,

});
